# Heatmap using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following rows:

```
    protein   IHD          CM         ARR         VD        CHD           CCD         VOO      
0   q9uku9  0.000000    0.039457    0.032901    0.014793    0.006614    0.006591    0.000000    
1   o75461  0.000000    0.005832    0.027698    0.000000    0.000000    0.006634    0.000000
```

etc.

I want a heatmap of the disease names (IHD, CM, etc) on the X axis with the protein name on the y=axis. I'm running into a float issue since the protein column is in letters. On my heatmap, I want the protein name to show though, so it wouldn't be helpful to just drop the entire column. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to drop the protein column from the dataframe.

Editing with the suggestion from the comments.

Also, the solution encompasses the case where you have a large list of diseases.

```
import seaborn as sns
list_proteins = df['protein'].unique()
y = df["protein"]
df = df.drop(['protein'], axis=1)
column_name_list = df.columns.tolist()   
sns.heatmap(df, xticklabels=column_name_list , yticklabels=list_proteins)
```

Comment: The data set is very large though, I'm unable to type each protein name out. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: To get the list of `proteins` you can use `list_proteins = df['protein'].unique()`.

Comment: @MarissaP, do you have a large list of X_labels too or is it just the protein?, if not, then ill edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DragonsCanDance The large list is just the proteins. The x axis is just the 7 diseases

Comment: @MarissaP, why is my proposed solution not working for you?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with the original question. Second, you have to decide what plotting tool you want to use.

There are multiples (I would suggest bokeh) and then depending on your choice, you have many options to tweak the appearance. If you provide working code example and an expected outcome, I can help you. However, I would be glad if you accept my answer as it clearly provides what you asked for in the first place. (The size depends on your size of data).

Answer (score 0):

Set your protein as index

```
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('protein', inplace = True)

plt.pcolor(df)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.show()
```